# Benchmarking in V10.1.0 not showing the correct verision of Mathematica?

Tags: bugs, system-performance

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 10.3**

---

[image]

This was done in V10.1.0, but it's showing that as if it was done in V10.0.0?

Computer Specs:(for those who are interested)

```
CPU:  i7 4790K
RAM:  32GB (4 X 8G)
GPU:  GTX980M
```

Just bought this for my research last week!

Comment: I reported this to Wolfram Technical Support some days ago `[CASE:2806619]`, and they said it would be fixed.

Comment: BTW could you please share your computer's tech specs? The benchmark looks impressive.

Comment: Yep, it's a minor bug. Its just that the Version string had a hard-coded value that did not get updated before release of 10.1.0.

Comment: @Felix Updated!

Comment: @StefanR Thanks! I can now edit the tag to `Bug`?

Comment: Well, my iMac 5K with i7-4790K, 32GB RAM, and R9 M295X, which only got benchmark of about 2.3 with mma 10.0.2 on OS X...

Comment: @Felix Perhaps switch to windows? or upgrade to 10.1.0? If we go to a chat, maybe we can compare some details on the benchmark report? I have no idea how to start one here.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu I remembered when I upgraded to mma 10.1 on my notebook, there was a benchmark improvement. I will try that on my iMac in my summer break

Comment: @ChenStatsYu unfortunately my iMac is at home and I don't have access to it :( Comparing the results for my notebook on OS X and Windows, it seems that windows always has better benchmarks.

Comment: @Felix I think you would be interested in [(69404)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69404/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed as of version 10.3.0.

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1610/12) and may want to comment (depending on your needs).

Comment: There is still a tiny problem in V10.2. The text version number is still WRONG.

Comment: @Chen Thanks, I did not notice it. The plain text report is also correct, but the footer does indeed say "This WolframMark report was created with Wolfram Mathematica 10.0".

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to say.