# Benchmarking problem in V11.3 on Win7/10 X64

Tags: bugs, benchmarking

I am the guy that likes to use `BenchmarkReport[]`,see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80696/benchmarking-in-v10-1-0-not-showing-the-correct-verision-of-mathematica) for example.
I noticed this loooong time ago after 11.3 was released, but never reported it.
I wonder if Wolfram making lots of changes to the `Output` of the format, but there seem to always be a problematic area to get the layout correct?

[image]

```
Needs["Benchmarking`"]
BenchmarkReport[]
```

Tested on both Win7 and Win10 (RS5).

Comment: It's a bug. Unfortunately reporting it here doesn't guarantee anything will be done about it. I'd recommend reporting it to Wolfram directly.

Comment: The poor layout does not actually have an affect on the results of your test though. So this is relatively inconsequential.

Comment: I vaguely remember something like this and I think it was fixed with a paclet update. I no longer see the problem. I wonder why yours hasn't updated.

Comment: @user6014  yes. Just thought someone might have more insight. I thought that the "layout" looks roughly the same. Why would something go wrong?

Comment: @Szabolcs I see this on both win 7/10 (V11.3). Is it not the latest?

Comment: I can't find the thread where this was discussed. Can you try `PacletUpdate["Benchmarking"]`? If that doesn't work, `PacletInstall["Benchmarking"]`.  Even the latest version receives additional updates over the internet. They are installed silently. This should get auto-installed if you use Mma for ~3 days and you have an internet connection.

Comment: @Szabolcs I see. I recently updated to Win10 (today is the 2nd day)

Comment: @Szabolcs `PacletUpdate["Benchmarking"]` sorted!

Answer (score 7):

As Suggested by @Szabolcs, using `PacletUpdate["Benchmarking"]`, it solved the problem.

If anyone provides more insight into this. I will accept as a better answer.