# Feasibility Beowulf Cluster with Raspberry Pi's running Mathematica?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Allegedly the Raspberry Pi comes equipped with a full version of Mathematica. I know that Beowulf clusters have been built from Raspberry Pi's. Now would it be possible to use such a cluster to do parallel computing using the Mathematica version on the Raspberry Pi's?

Comment: Please see the benchmarks [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39685/731); even if it is possible you will need an impractical amount of Raspberry Pi's to make it run at a decent speed.

Comment: Sadly, not feasible then. The idea was too good to be true :-(

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to use several RPis for parallel computation with Mathematica.  It may be necessary to set up the subkernels manually (i.e. specify the IP of each unit, set up key-based authentication, etc.), but it should definitely be possible.  I only have one RPi so I cannot try :)

Comment: That would be an interesting project to try.

Comment: What Pickett says is true: a cluster of RPis won't be able to compete with a single modern desktop.  But you can still achieve some improvement relative to a single RPi, just like we can connect several desktops together into a grid and run parallel Mathematica on that.

Comment: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/420511

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the link. Interesting.